# How to Suppress Duplicate reocords in Total value for crystal report

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

This is Following details Called

For exam

```
Date      type   id     acc      amount
12/01/2     1     01    100      1000
12/01/2     2     02    200      3000
12/01/2     2     02    300      5000
Crystal report Total -----------------------
                                18000
```

But Actual Total for 9000 amount , How to solve issue

I tried in grouping also.

Pleas Help

Prakash

Comment: Use running totals. Better would be redesign report/query to avoid duplicate rows altogether, but that is not always possible.

Comment: your group by is on which column friend?

Answer (score 0):

use the option `Select Distinct Records` in `Database` tab

Comment: This seems like bad advice. Do you know, why there are duplicate records? Maybe not all fields are identical, maybe some fields are sometimes identical, sometimes not - these "distinct" options either in queries on in reports indicate bad design and usually are very hard to debug.